# What's the most concise way to replace items in a vector by items in another vector?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Say, I have a `mxn` matrix M, whose column 1 contains values like -1, 0, 4, 12, 27, ..., and they can occur multiple times. These are not sequential numbers, so I would like to replace wherever they occur in M with corresponding natural numbers (i.e., the smallest value in the column should be replaced by 1, the second smallest by 2, the third smallest by 3, and so on).

I can easily do this using a `for` loop running over the length of the column, and writing the replacement condition for each unique value in the column:

```
for i=1:size(unique(M(:,1)),1)
    M(M(:,1)==-1)=1;
    M(M(:,1)==0)=2;
    M(M(:,1)==4)=3;
    M(M(:,1)==12)=4;
    M(M(:,1)==27)=5;
    ...
    ...
    ...
end
```

However, this can get to be tedious if the number of unique elements in the column is large. I would like to know a better, more concise way of doing this, utilizing MATLAB vectorization. So, I tried to use the `changem` function to replace all values in the original data by natural numbers:

```
changem(M(:,1), unique(M(:,1))', [1:1:numel(unique(M(:,1)))]);
```

But this doesn't work. It only replaces the first 2 or 3 unique numbers in M. Why?

**EDIT: Sample example.** Say the first few rows of my matrix M are as follows:

```
91  620011  sunday  1.43309E+12     
92  620194  sunday  1.43309E+12 25.0048276  121.3041219
91  620072  sunday  1433087996  25.038848   121.455705
91  620177  sunday  1.43309E+12     
91  620268  sunday  1.43309E+12 24.79293518 120.9506341
92  620266  sunday  1433087991      
107 620092  sunday  1.43309E+12 24.86219998 120.9648107
1   36581192    sunday  1433087990      
91  620268  sunday  1.43309E+12     
91  619897  sunday  1.43309E+12 24.9161251  121.2068644
```

Then, assuming 0 is the smallest element, 91 is the 10th smallest element, 92 is the 11th smallest element, and 107 is the 15th smallest element, I want the matrix to become this:

```
10  620011  sunday  1.43309E+12     
11  620194  sunday  1.43309E+12 25.0048276  121.3041219
10  620072  sunday  1433087996  25.038848   121.455705
10  620177  sunday  1.43309E+12     
10  620268  sunday  1.43309E+12 24.79293518 120.9506341
11  620266  sunday  1433087991      
15  620092  sunday  1.43309E+12 24.86219998 120.9648107
1   36581192    sunday  1433087990      
10  620268  sunday  1.43309E+12     
10  619897  sunday  1.43309E+12 24.9161251  121.2068644
```

Answer (score 1):

The third output of unique should do it for you:

```
[~,~,M(:,1)] = unique(M(:,1))
```

Comment: But my matrix M has other columns too. And I have to keep all the corresponding rows same.

Comment: @Kristada673 then please add an example input and output. Use a small matrix, maybe *5*-by-*3*. It's not clear from your question what you want to do to the other columns...

Comment: @Kristada673 oh are you saying if the number `x` becomes `y` in the first column after ranking it, then all `x`s in the rest of the matrix must also become `y`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But additionally,what I am saying is, after changing the numbers in the first column, they should remain in their respective places. I mean, they should not get sorted.

Comment: It did get sorted using the first code you sent: `[~,~,M_ranked] = unique(M(:,1))`, which is when I replied. Anyway, I have added an example using sample data in the question details.

Comment: @Kristada673, no it does not sort using that first line. Also your example does not make sense, what happened to numbers `2` through `9`?

Comment: The matrix is huge (58 million rows). So, the numbers 2 through 9 appear somewhere down the line  :-)  I just took the first 10 rows for this sample.

Comment: @Kristada673 there is no point in posting example data if it's not complete! The whole point is that it's an *example*. Make a small matrix and show the *exact* output for the input you post. Either way, the code I posted does do exactly what you want. There is no sorting.

Comment: Hmmm. It works. I must have given some other column or something, by mistake, the first time. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, do you have some idea why my code did not work?

Comment: @Kristada673 sorry I don't have the mapping toolbox so I can't test your code. Looking at the docs, what you wrote looks reasonable

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

First you make one big list:

```
B = reshape(M,[],m*n)
```

Then sort it:

```
[~,key] = sort(B)
```

and make a Matrix:

```
_M = reshape(key,size(M))
```

Cant test it right now, sorry

---

If you use [`[B,key] = sort(___)`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html?searchHighlight=sort), `key` is the vector you want

Comment: I do not want to sort the first column. Perhaps I was unclear in the question. Let me add an edit to the question details, and you can check after 2 minutes.

Comment: @Dan yep, did not get it the first time reading, adapted the answer, thanks